# MVC Error returning JsonResult of GeoCoordinate

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, model-view-controller, jsonresult

Ok so I have a class called Marker, which has a `GeoCoordinate` in it (`System.Device.Location` namespace)

```
public class Marker
{
    public string ContentHtml { get; set; }
    public GeoCoordinate Location { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
}
```

And this is my controller:

```
[HttpGet]
public JsonResult GetNearbyResourceLocations(double? lat, double? lng)
{
    var markers = new List<Marker>();

    markers.Add(new Marker
    {
        Title = "Titlu potential",
        ContentHtml = "strada Mihai Eminescu 666",
        Location = new GeoCoordinate
        {
            Latitude = 44.4455937000000000,
            Longitude = 26.1163411000000000
        }
    });

    return this.Json(markers, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

From the view I call this with $.ajax.

I always end up in the error: function(response) part of Ajax.
If I don't set the Location (`GeoCoordinate`), it works.

Yeah, I know I could use another class, with Lat/Long but I want to use the GeoCoordinate. I wonder why it doesn't work :(

Comment: what is the problem? is it that `lat` and `lng` values not being mapped to the controller?

Comment: If I set the Location (in the controller), the ajax is error. If I don't set the Location, the ajax is success!    I fixed the problem by declaring Latitude and Longitude separately, without using the GeoCoordinate class... it works like that. I was just curious why it didn't with GeoCoordinate, it seems to have a problem jsoning complex types (?)